OpenSearch - How can I get record pairs matching two queries
I'm working with an OpenSearch database and I need to pull some data that I would use a JOIN to get from an SQL database but I'm not sure the best way to get it from OpenSearch.
For context I'm working with a dataset of multiple versions of the same text in different languages. So we have a single index full of "records" and each record has a group ID that ties the record to the same text in x number of different languages.
I am working on building some tooling to search our database and I'd like to allow the users to search for details about both the original language and a target language. For example, they could search for groups where English says "Hello World" and Spanish says "Hola Mundo".
The problem is that in some cases there may not be a match to my query in one of the two languages. For example, maybe there's the English "Hello World" but no Spanish "Hola Mundo" so I wouldn't want to return the English result, because there isn't overlap with the Spanish query.
Is there any good way to do this in OpenSearch? In SQL I would simply do a join and load each side with it's applicable query. But I can't seem to find a way to do something similar with OS Query DSL.
The only option I've found so far would be to search one side (English for example), then add the group IDs as a parameter for the search against the other side (Spanish for example). The only problem here is that we could be dealing with complex queries on both sides and hundreds of thousands (potentially even millions) of results on each side as well and even just getting a count of results could be slow and take multiple database calls. For our use case, ideally we could get the first 500 or so results, then a total count of the other results. Would there be any way to do this?

Have you considered storing all languages in the same record as nested objects or creating a group ID record as a parent record and making language-specific records as children?

We've talked about that briefly, but don't have the time/resources to restructure our data right now. Ideally we would change to using nested objects, but that would be further down the road.

That would be the way to do it. Alternative is to use something like ids query, but you probably already know that. To make it fast and efficient you have to guarantee that records in the same group are allocated in the same shard, which means you need to restructure your data and use nested objects or join fields. Good luck!
